# Giving / Taking exam

Tags: speech

Do we give or take exam ?
Please clarify the difference of both.

In normal english, if we give something then it is giving, then it will b giving exam. But everyone says "giving exam" is wrong.

Comment: Quick answer: **take**.

Answer (score 3):

A teacher **gives** you an exam/test/quiz. You **take** that exam/test/quiz. And then you either **pass** it or **fail** it.